# How to override $ and $$ in Chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to use my own `$` and `$$` in Chrome console only for developing purposes. But site uses jQuery. But when I do something like `const $ = function() {}` it overrides jQuery `$` in global scope and breaks site. I can't modify site. So how to set `$` only for console and save jQuery `$` for scripts?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: I can't modify site.